# Как сделать жирным шрифт который подгружается через font-face

Tags: шрифты

Версии жирного шрифта нету, но нужно сделать более жирным шрифт, может какой то редактор использовать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пора уже принять как должное, что одни и те же шрифты в макете и браузере могут отображаться по-разному. Более того шрифты могут отличаться в браузерах разных производителей. Если вам очень критично точное отображение, то есть несколько вариантов:

- Как вам уже и посоветовал [@soledar10](/users/13968/soledar10), использовать text-shadow и, если не устраивает расстояние между буквами, то letter-spacing.
- Использовать другой шрифт, близкий по начертанию к исходному.
- Попробовать альтернативные варианты подключения шрифтов (Cufon, etc).

Comment: Я принимаю как должное, а заказчик нет. Надо искать похожий шрифт а это проблематично